# what's the probability that permutation has k fixed points and $\sigma(1) = k$

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

given a random $\sigma \in S_n$ a permutation from [n] to [n] (n >= 2), lets assume that the permutation $\sigma $ has exactly $k \in$ {$0,1,...,n$} fixed points.

what's the probability under a uniform probability space that $\sigma(1) = k$.

---

my try:

P is the probability function and $A_i$ is the event when k = i.

so ans = P($\cup_{i=1}^{n-2}A_i$) = $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}P(A_i)$

now we need to find $P(A_i) $ which i believe we did something similar in another post - i am not sure if the rest of my solution is true and i will be pleased if someone will complete it or give another solution. thanks.

Comment: Are the two $k$s the same?

Comment: yes but k's value isn't netter for the condition